# Вывод данных из таблицы google docs Spreadsheets в виде массива PHP

Tags: zend-framework, google-api, google-spreadsheet, google-docs-api

Доброго времени суток, примерно уже четвертый день мучаюсь не могу найти актуальный способ подключиться к google docs  Spreadsheets  и вытянуть из них данные. Пробовал с помощью Zend Gdata(качал с оф. сайта) подключиться указав логин и пароль, вызывалось исключение: DOMDocument cannot parse XML...(Почитав в инете наткнулся и  не раз, на то что это из-за причины обновления google  auth 1.0 -> auth 2.0, но сам не уверен). Второй вариант я пробовал, по google'вской  [инструкции](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started), где в конце необходимо, запустить из командной строки скриптик и получить код, да в итоге мне выдало ошибку в консоле. Третий вариант,  я использовал [инструкцию](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started) , но там не оказалось библиотеки Spreadsheets, для работы с таблицами. Пробовал варианты еще, самописные, но успехом не увенчались.  Таблицы не мои, редактировать их не могу, имеется только ссылка. Если кто-то работал с  этим чудом или есть ссылочка на рабочий ресурс, плиз выручите. Идеально будет конечно, если есть инструкция по шаговая, мне то всего надо вытянуть таблицу, в виде массива или целиком, я уже с js вытяну все что мне надо.

Comment: _пробовал, по google'вской инструкции...  да в итоге мне выдало ошибку в консоле._, какая ошибка?

Comment: Maxim. Добрый, вот такого рода ошибка, в ответ на верификационный код отправленный мною:                                         Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with mes
sage 'cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certifi
cate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)' in C:\xampp\htdocs
\temp.site\google-api-php-client\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactor
y.php:187
Stack trace:

Comment: Продолжение:                                                                                           #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\temp.site\google-api-php-client\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\
Handler\CurlFactory.php(150): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Ob
ject(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\temp.site\google-api-php-client\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\
Handler\CurlFactory.php(103): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object
(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(
    GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory))

Comment: Продолжение:                                                                                                                #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\temp.site\google-api-php-client\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\
Handler\CurlHandler.php(43): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(Guzzl
eHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\Eas in C:\xampp\htdocs\tem
p.site\google-api-php-client\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.ph
p on line 187

Answer (score -1):

Полная документация от Гугл: [`spreadsheets.values`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/).

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/165937)

Comment: Ссылка ведёт на гугл api, если страница будет изменена, то решение указанное здесь не будет работать.

Comment: @MikhailZamkevich, имя функции является ответом независимо от ссылки.